# ManyToMany Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get mutiple checkboxes selected on a form. I'm using the following methodology of populating a table with a series of choices using ManytoManyFields. CHOICES are copied into the table with a script. However after selecting the checkboxes I get the following error:

```
Select a valid choice. [u'_CU', u'_EN'] is not one of the available choices.
```

IN the model:

```
class A(models.Model):
    MyPersonalityType = models.ManyToManyField(P)



CHOICES = (
     ('_NN', 'Choice 1...'),
     ('_GK', ''),
     ('_SA', ''),
     ('_ES', ''),
     ('_SH', ''),
     ('_CU', ''),
     ('_EN', ''),
)

class P(models.Model):
    slug = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=32)
    title = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=124)
```

In the form:

```
MyPersonalityType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=CHOICES, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
```

I add the code with:

```
for tag,des in CHOICES:
    new = P(slug=tag, title=des)
    new.save()
```

The template is:

```
{% for field in form %}
    <div class="fieldWrapper">
        {{ field.errors }}
        {{ field.label_tag }}: {{ field }}
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: There has to be more code than this - you've got a ManyToManyField just floating there. Can you post it?

Comment: done - this is all the code.

Comment: That's the entire code for your app? Where does `MyPersonalityType` come from?

Comment: @sdk900 I tried that in the forms, but I get the following: 'module' object has no attribute 'CheckBox'. Why would I do this? There is no widget named Checkbox.

Comment: @ChristianTernus Forgot the forms. Now added. Still now joy in getting this to work.

Comment: This sounds like you are having trouble with the form and not the model. choice_field = forms.ChoiceField(widget=forms.CheckBoxSelectMultiple(), choices=CHOICES) Simply a Typo on the form type. I see you have now added form code which was not there before.